# Transaction hash as contract method parameter

Tags: contract-invocation

How to send the generated transaction hash as the solidity contract parameter through JSON RPC API call to the blockchain.

Comment: you cannot send the hash as a parameter in the same transaction, since the hash is also a function of the parameters. otherwise, just get the tx hash and include it as a parameter for a later transaction like you would anything else